# Wired connection is slow

Tags: networking

I recently installed Ubuntu on my computer and I only get about 150-250 KB/s for my 16Mb/s internet connection. I've tried installing Ubuntu 16.4.5, installing Ubuntu 18.10 on minimal with no third-party apps, disabling IPV6, changing DNS, using wget command and other ways to download and I still have the problem.
Whenever I start a download, the speed is all fine but over a few seconds, it decreases to 150-250 KB/s. 
Before Ubuntu, I had Windows and there was no problem. My other devices, Laptop PC & Android phone, get fine a fine speed.

Comment: You should determine if this is happening within your network as well. You can transfer a dummy file between local hosts and see what the throughput is. Simplify as much as possible and then work out from there.

Comment: have you try different internet resources? http://www.speedtest.net ?

Comment: Share something on Laptop and test local speed.